# Is there any good way to keep CodeMirror from initializing as a white box

Tags: css, loading, styling, codemirror

I'm using Codemirror 5.62.3 and the 'monokai' theme ( with a dark background ). When I reload the page, the CodeMirror is initialized as a small white box before the styling takes effect. Is there any good way to avoid this behaviour? I've tried only rendering the Codemirror once it's value has been loaded, however there is still a brief period where the box is white

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but fixed by setting all textareas to:

```
textarea {
    outline:none;
    background: rgb(0,0,0,0);
    border: none;
    resize: none;
}
```